# Short story. If a family has a third child, it is announced that for the next 24 hours killing the father will be perfectly legal

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think I read this in the 80s. In the future overpopulation is a problem and all families are limited to two children. (It is not the Ender's game series which has a similar restriction on family size.)

A husband and wife believe this law is wrong and their third child is born. An announcement is made by the government that for the next 24 hours, killing the child's father will be pefectly legal.

Several crazy violent men attempt to kill him. The father ends up killing one of them in self-defence. The government is happy with this outcome. The population has been reduced by one and they have got rid of a dangerous person who enjoys killing. They announce that it is no longer legal to kill the father.

He returns to his wife who is happy he survived and complains about how awful the population limiting law is.

> The story ends with her telling her husband that she is once more pregnant. He has a condemned sinking feeling.

Comment: It is pretty sexist that only the father has his life put in danger when both parents decided to have a third child.

Comment: It gets worse when you read the text. The authorities say the father "alone" is responsible for violating the law!

Comment: @JudithJones It's about protecting the vulnerable newborn.  Killing the mother is worse for the newborn than killing the father.

Comment: Well, in the context of controlling overpopulation, protecting a newborn shouldn't be a priority.  And in theory, if the aim is to reduce the population, removing the mother should be more effective.  Besides all moral considerations.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is undoubtedly ["A Criminal Act" by Harry Harrison](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45532), which appeared in Analog in January 1967 and subsequently in other collections. The [full text of that issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gEu2OFZmZD6RpcL93dmtwn7OqUZldF0H/view) is linked from [its ISFDB page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56792).

The hapless father is Benedict Vernall. The story opens with a bailiff breaking down his door to tell him that "pursuant to the Criminal Birth Act of 1993" he is "no longer protected from bodily injury by the forces of this sovereign state", because of having had a third child. Benedict believes in "natural law, the sanctity of life, the inviolability of marriage" and the couple has refused birth control and an offered abortion. But the state deems that the family has "one consumer more than is prescribed by law" and holds him reponsible.

As Benedict also refuses quiet euthanasia, another man, Mortimer, is selected as a volunteer to hunt him down. He has 24 hours, and is supplied with weapons from an official cache. There are many prospective volunteers who eagerly fought for the chance, including one who has to be sedated after he fails to qualify - this matches the "crazy violent men" part of the question. Mortimer himself is calm and philosophical, presenting himself as an agent of rationality who is simply carrying out society's need to rid itself of the "selfish".

Most of the rest of the story is an interchange of bullets and philosophy as Benedict and Mortimer proceed to disagree about whether the former should die.

In the end, as in the question,

> Benedict's wife Maria welcomes him home after Mortimer's death. He announces that since he has survived and there is "one less mouth" to feed, the baby will get a full food ration and they will no longer be in danger. But she says:
>
> "I really didn't want to tell you before, not bother you with all this other trouble going on. But there's going to be..." She dropped her eyes.
>
> "What?" he asked incredulously. "You can't possibly mean..."
>
> "But I do." She patted the rounded mound of her midriff. "Aren't we lucky?"
>
> All he could do was look up at her, his mouth wide and gaping like some helpless fish cast up on the shore.

A comment on the question remarks that it is sexist to hold the father solely responsible. It certainly does appear that Maria is not a target for Mortimer, and the Vernall children aren't directly considered to be in danger - they send the older two to her mother to keep them out of harm's way, but there's no sense that anyone is going to hunt them down. In a side conversation,

> Mortimer says that there are "countless frustrated women willing to volunteer for battle to even the score" against any unwed mother who has more than one child. So apparently there is a parallel regime for women. Still markedly sexist, but slightly differently expressed.

Comment: So... Mortimer's a hypocrite or something? He presumably refused birth control, and stuff, otherwise how could he have another child after "the older two" also exist?

Comment: @Malady are you reading "the older two" as being Mortimer's children? I understood that sentence to mean Benedict and Maria's children aren't in danger and the older two of _those_ are sent to Maria's mother (the youngest being the baby who presumably needs to be with Maria).

Comment: edited to clarify that it is indeed the two elder Vernall children

Comment: Ah. I got confused between Benedict and Mortimer. I somehow thought Maria was Mortimer's wife and stuff. So Benedict's gotta do this again. Damn. HA!